# Preventing file copying on Android device when app is running

Tags: android, adb, drm

So I want to prevent people from copying files out of my app while it is running.

1) Is there an easier way to detect if files are being copied off my device than through checking if the adb daemon is running?

2) Is there an easy way to  enumerate all processes running on the Android OS from an app?

I know Android is not a very secure system, but I would at least like to make it difficult for people to copy files off of my app.

**EDIT**

To clarify my problem, all the files I have stored on the disk are encrypted. My concern is that I need to unencrpyt these files when accessing them in my app. I am trying to prevent someone from stealing these files while the app is running. I already delete the unencrypted files if someone exits out of the app.

Also, I was focused on adb because I was considering trying to delete unencrypted files if connected by usb. However, I know you can still run adb over wifi on a rooted phone. Now that I think about it, you can probably transfer files over by wifi on a rooted phone as well.

Also, obviously not having the files on the device is not an option.

Comment: Have you considered encrypting the files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem focused on `adb`, for unknown reasons.

With respect to internal storage, users cannot copy files off of internal storage of a device using `adb`, unless the device is rooted. And if the device is rooted, they do not need `adb` to copy files.

With respect to external storage, that is specifically designed to allow any app, or the user, to copy files from it, again without `adb`.

Hence, trying to detect `adb` is pointless.

> I know Android is not a very secure system, but I would at least like to make it difficult for people to copy files off of my app.

Then don't put the files on the device in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you mean that a user would use your application and put his phone on USB mode and proceed to transfer file off your application folder while your application is still running ?

If some files are needed in order for your application to function at runtime, can't your just make them private to your application ? Like illustrated in [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal). Or simply don't put files on the device :)

Comment: This will only be worth it if it can protect against copying on rooted devices. I currently don't make them private to my application because some of the files are media files and they need to be read by a VideoView. I could write some custom mediaplayer code, but this will only be worth it if I can protect the content on rooted devices.

Comment: Sadly users with root access can do what ever they want regardless of resource exposure. Even SharedPreferences are accessible with root access :/

Comment: The only files I had to put on devices were XML files, which I encrypted. But I don't know how one would go about protecting media files, best of luck to you my friend.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "copying files out of my app" means (is your app designed to show/provide files, or are you referring to the resources and other files *used* by your app).

In any case, you're wasting your time. Android is a very open platform and (particularly on rooted devices) people will always find a way to copy data if they want to.

Comment: My concern is on rooted devices.